# ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'useStyles' before initialization React Collapse Component, axios get data material ui useStyles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am trying to render data from backend (array with objects) and hide part of it under collapse button with use of material - ui in React.
The code works just fine if I write all lines in one component - ShowMore.

But the things got tricky when i try to make a separate component, a reusable Collapse Button.

When i try to pass a children object in order to render a downloaded data wrapped in CollapseBtn and change styles i got a
"ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'useStyles' before initialization"

Here is code in main component ShowMore

```
import CollapseBtn from "./components/CollapseBtn";
const ShowMore = () => {
  let myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
  const api = `https://someBackendAppLink`;
  const { download } = useLogic(api, myToken);

  return (
    <Page>
      <SG.Box>
        <S.Header>
          <S.Title h1 primary>
            Certifications
          </S.Title>
        </S.Header>
        {download && (
          <div>
            <Typography>
              {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                .slice(0, 4)
                .map((obj) => (
                  <S.CardDiv>
                    <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                    <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                  </S.CardDiv>
                ))}
            </Typography>
            <CollapseBtn>
              <Typography>
                {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                  .slice(4)
                  .map((obj) => (
                    <S.CardDiv>
                      <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                      <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                    </S.CardDiv>
                  ))}
              </Typography>
            </CollapseBtn>
          </div>
        )}
      </SG.Box>
    </Page>
  );
};
```

and code from separate Collapsebtn

```
import Collapse from "@material-ui/core/Collapse";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";

const CollapseBtn = ({ children }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    expand: {
      transform: "rotate(0deg)",
      marginLeft: "auto",
      transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
      }),
    },
    expandOpen: {
      transform: "rotate(180deg)",
    },
  }));
  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <IconButton
        className={clsx(classes.expand, {
          [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
        })}
        onClick={handleExpandClick}
        aria-expanded={expanded}
        aria-label="show more"
      >
        <ExpandMoreIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
        {children}
      </Collapse>
    </>
  );
};

export default CollapseBtn;
```

And here is a WORKING code made in one main component (instead of Collapsebtn i wrapp all hidden objects in Collapse from material ui)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  expand: {
    transform: "rotate(0deg)",
    marginLeft: "auto",
    transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
    }),
  },
  expandOpen: {
    transform: "rotate(180deg)",
  },
}));

const ShowMore = ({ className }) => {
  let myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
  const api = `https://someBackendApiData`;
  const { download } = useLogic(api, myToken);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <Page>
      <SG.Box>
        <S.Header>
          <S.Title h1 primary>
            Certifications
          </S.Title>
        </S.Header>
        {download && (
          <div>
            <Typography>
              {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                .slice(0, 4)
                .map((obj) => (
                  <S.CardDiv>
                    <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                    <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                  </S.CardDiv>
                ))}
            </Typography>

            <IconButton
              className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
              })}
              onClick={handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography>
                  {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                    .slice(4)
                    .map((obj) => (
                      <S.CardDiv>
                        <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                        <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                      </S.CardDiv>
                    ))}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        )}
      </SG.Box>
    </Page>
  );
};
```

Whats wrong ? How to fix it ?

Comment: You are calling ```useStyles()``` before declaring it. Place ```const classes = useStyles();``` after the call of ```makeStyles()```

Comment: You are right, i used it too early. It works now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that `useStyles` is not initialized. Which means. The function should go inside the component.

```
const ShowMore = ({ className }) => {
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      expand: {
        transform: "rotate(0deg)",
        marginLeft: "auto",
        transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
          duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
        }),
      },
      expandOpen: {
        transform: "rotate(180deg)",
      },
    }));
  let myToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
  const api = `https://someBackendApiData`;
  const { download } = useLogic(api, myToken);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };

  return (
    <Page>
      <SG.Box>
        <S.Header>
          <S.Title h1 primary>
            Certifications
          </S.Title>
        </S.Header>
        {download && (
          <div>
            <Typography>
              {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                .slice(0, 4)
                .map((obj) => (
                  <S.CardDiv>
                    <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                    <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                  </S.CardDiv>
                ))}
            </Typography>

            <IconButton
              className={clsx(classes.expand, {
                [classes.expandOpen]: expanded,
              })}
              onClick={handleExpandClick}
              aria-expanded={expanded}
              aria-label="show more"
            >
              <ExpandMoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography>
                  {download.data.advancedProfile.certifications
                    .slice(4)
                    .map((obj) => (
                      <S.CardDiv>
                        <div>{obj.title}</div> <div>{obj.link}</div>
                        <div>{obj.category}</div> <div>{obj.date}</div>
                      </S.CardDiv>
                    ))}
                </Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        )}
      </SG.Box>
    </Page>
  );
};
```